# Chart.js limit the display size of the chart

Tags: asp.net, chart.js

I am using Chart.js in my ASP.NET project. I have a bar chart like this:
[image: bar chart with issues]
As you can see, for some bars users won't be able to see their labels. I am thinking about making the display size of the chart smaller so that there will be enough space on the right for the labels. But how to do that？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that by setting some right-padding *(as required)* for your chart layout.

```
options: {
   layout: {
      padding: {
         right: 100 //set as you wish
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Statistics',
         data: [3, 1, 2, 5, 4],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.8)',
      }]
   },
   options: {
      layout: {
         padding: {
            right: 100 //set as you wish
         }
      },
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: Welcome!­­­­­­­

Comment: Sure :) (comments length requirement)